# Redireccionamiento 301 funciona en local pero no en el servidor

Tags: .htaccess

Vuelvo a tener problemas con htaccess. Trabajando en local me funcionan sin ningún problema, pero en el servidor no me redirige bien.

Por ejemplo teniendo esta URL antigua:

```
https://www.laxtore.com/Juegos/Xbox-One/37/EA-SPORTS-FIFA-17/
```

Me debería redirigir a:

```
https://www.laxtore.com/es/juegos/xbox-one/37/EA-SPORTS-FIFA-17/
```

Pero me redirige a esta URL:

```
https://www.laxtore.com/home/admin/web/laxtore.com/public_html/es/juegos/xbox-one/37/EA-SPORTS-FIFA-17/
```

Me pasa con todos los redireccionamientos 301 que he aplicado. Para el caso de la URL que he puesto lo redirecciono de esta forma:

```
RewriteRule ^Juegos/Xbox-One/ es/juegos/xbox-one/ [R=301,L]
```

No entiendo dónde está el problema. Dejo claro que en local me han funcionado absolutamente todas, pero cuando lo he subido al servidor no me funciona ninguna. Justo antes de los redireccionamientos tengo esto:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^laxtore.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.laxtore.com [L,R=301,NC]

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` sólo es necesario una vez al inicio, y un grupo de `RewriteCond`s no van solas, siempre tienene que ir seguida de una `RewriteRule` (son las **cond**iciones para esa regla)

Answer (score 0):

Asegurate de tener bien configurado el Document Root en tu `httpd.conf`.

```py
DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/laxtore.com/public_html
```

reiniciando Apache para que tome la configuración.

Y en el .htaccess, en los casos en los que Apache está teniendo problemas para ubicar en qué carpeta está, hay que usar `RewriteBase`

```py
# si estás en el document root de tu web
RewriteBase /

#   o en cualquier otra carpeta
# RewriteBase /otra/carpeta
```